# How to fix UserWarning: An input could not be retrieved

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, google-colaboratory

I tried to run my code on google colab and I get the following error message:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:709: UserWarning: An input could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.We do not have any information on the lost sample.

I tried to search online and solve it but many methods are not working.
Thank you very much!

---

python 3.6

```
model.fit(getBW(batchSize, sampleRate=16000),steps_per_epoch = len(wavLabel)//batchSize, epochs=15,
                    validation_data=getTestBW(100),
                    validation_steps=5,
                    use_multiprocessing=False,
                    workers = 1,
                    callbacks=[

                        ModelCheckpoint("{epoch:02d}e-val_acc_{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5",
                                        monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='min', period=1),

                        keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.1, patience=10,
                                                          verbose=0, mode='min', epsilon=0.0001, cooldown=0,
                                                          min_lr=0),
                        TensorBoard(log_dir="./log1"),
])
```

Comment: I was wondering, have you found any solution on this? I'm facing the same warning and not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: This might not be the best solution, but I switched to TPU from GPU,without changing my code and I didn't have those warnings. Although a few warnings are totally okay. It is only a problem if we have an error.

Comment: You can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446290/