# UserWarning: The input 94 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 94 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.   UserWarning)

Im trying multi class classification with cnn using keras and I get this error during epochs. Dont know what cause this problem. I also use google colab and mount drive.

Comment: See if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446290/userwarning-an-input-could-not-be-retrieved-it-could-be-because-a-worker-has

Comment: same for here, google colab is a sh...

Comment: My answer in the same issue I have post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078064/8922718