# How to solve User Warning Image Retrieving Problem?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to solve this problem:-
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 49 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.

And does the val_accuracy get affected?

Comment: You should share your code so other people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this lead, they also faced the same problem and dealt with it too. Basically it is a warning message and does effect if you have a flaw in logic if not, then don't be worried.

[Here is the link, Hope it is useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58446290/11706592)