# The neural network model is training the first Epoch and reports Warning, and then continues the training cycle from the beginning

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The neural network model is training the first Epoch and reports Warning, and then continues the training cycle from the beginning. How can I solve it?

The neural network model reported an error during the first Epoch training.

```
“12872/21931 [================>.............] - ETA: 3:55:38 - loss: 1.8393 - accuracy: 0.7415/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 12494 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.”
```

Then it will continue to re-train from the first Epoch. How to solve this situation? Thank you!

Comment: have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446290/

Comment: Please take a look at what @Ruli has mentioned. If you need any further help please add a standalone code sample to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Ruli Yeah, I have read this link. But I still get the same error after reducing the batch_size from 128 to 16. So I really don’t know how to solve it.